# Error with polychoric correlations - "Some polytomous variables have fewer categories than they should"

Tags: r, psych

I try to do polychoric correlations with the command cor.ci of psych but get the following error. Do you know what's wrong with my data?

```
psych::cor.ci(myData , poly = TRUE)

> Some polytomous variables have fewer categories than they should.  Please check your data.   Potential bad items are   Error in mixedCor(data = x, c = NULL, p = p, d = d, smooth = smooth, correct = correct,
```

Here are my data (Participants had to answer on 4-point Likert scales; in all variables, at least 3 values were chosen by the participants):

```
myData <- structure(list(V1 = c(3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 
3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 
3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2), V2 = c(3, 
2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 
2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 
3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1), V3 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), 
V4 = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 0, 2, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1), V5 = c(2, 2, 
1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 
3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 
3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2), V6 = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1), V7 = c(0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -51L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: While I also get an error, it's different from yours. Is there something missing in your example?

Comment: The example just got edited. Do you still get the other error? And: What was your error?

Comment: An error and three warnings: Error in 1 + rho : non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In matpLower(x, nvar, gminx, gmaxx, gminy, gmaxy) :
  21 cells were adjusted for 0 values using the correction for continuity. Examine your data carefully.
2: In mclapply(1:n.iter, function(XX) { :
  all scheduled cores encountered errors in user code
3: In matrix(unlist(replicates), ncol = nvar * (nvar - 1)/2, byrow = TRUE) :
  data length [100] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of columns [21]

Comment: Debugging, it looks like it doesn't like `V3` for some reason. It does a check to see if `length(table(x)) != (max(x,na.rm=TRUE) - min(x,na.rm=TRUE)+1)` and `length(table(myData$V3))` is `3` , while the right side of that formula totals `4`. Having no knowledge of polychoric correlations, I can't help beyond that.